# Apply function then Filter DataFrame

Tags: python, filter, pandas

I am currently trying to create a new column to then filter on:

```
df['filterSalaryLoc'] = df[True if df['distance'] <= 25 & df['compensation_right'] else False]
```

This is how the DF Looks:

```
      distance      compensation_right 
1     20.299433         True
2     1014.258732       True   
3     1027.524228       True
4     5556.81612        True
5     926.003129        True
6     19.832819         True
7     1.489066          True
8     434.355273        True
9     23.647016         True
```

Where if the column entry is false, then it will be extracted out. However it is not working and creates an error here: `df['filterSalaryLoc'] = df[True if df['distance'] <= 25 & df['compensation_right'] else False]`. Anyone know what's going wrong?

Comment: Try putting parentheses around the first part of your condition: `if (df['distance'] <= 25) & df['compensation_right']`.

Comment: I still have a value error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

Find where your condition is true with `df[(df.distance <= 25) & (df.compensation_right)]` (you don't need the `[True if ... else False]`). Then take those rows (the `.index`) and make a new column that's True at those indices and `NaN` everywhere else.

```
In [7]: df.loc[df[(df.distance <= 25) & (df.compensation_right)].index, 'filterSalaryLoc'] = True

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
      distance compensation_right filterSalaryLoc
1    20.299433               True            True
2  1014.258732               True             NaN
3  1027.524228               True             NaN
4  5556.816120               True             NaN
5   926.003129               True             NaN
6    19.832819               True            True
7     1.489066               True            True
8   434.355273               True             NaN
9    23.647016               True            True

[9 rows x 3 columns]
```

Fill the `NaN`s with False:

```
In [9]: df.filterSalaryLoc.fillna(False, inplace=True)

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
      distance compensation_right filterSalaryLoc
1    20.299433               True            True
2  1014.258732               True           False
3  1027.524228               True           False
4  5556.816120               True           False
5   926.003129               True           False
6    19.832819               True            True
7     1.489066               True            True
8   434.355273               True           False
9    23.647016               True            True

[9 rows x 3 columns]
```

If you have pandas `0.13` or later installed, the first line can be replaced by:

```
In [13]: df.loc[df.query('distance <= 25 and compensation_right').index, 'filterSalaryLoc'] = True
```

Answer (score 2):

I think perhaps you could do the assignment this way:

```
In [10]: df['filterSalaryLoc'] = (df['distance']<=25) & (df['compensation_right'])

In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
      distance compensation_right filterSalaryLoc
0    20.299433               True            True
1  1014.258732               True           False
2  1027.524228               True           False
3  5556.816120               True           False
4   926.003129               True           False
5    19.832819               True            True
6     1.489066               True            True
7   434.355273               True           False
8    23.647016               True            True
```

The parentheses are necessary on the right-hand side, since without them `df['distance']<=25 & df['compensation_right']` is parsed like

```
In [18]: df['distance']<=(25 & df['compensation_right'])
Out[18]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
dtype: bool
```

(Note this is all False.)

Comment: Much cleaner than my solution. I'm not sure why I felt the need to index with the result from the query, rather than just assigning it.